# Jmeter with Thai language

Tags: jmeter

I can not type Thai language like "สวัสดีครับ" in HTTP Request(Body data) and every where in jmeter it show me ??????, and I don't know what to do.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTrmT.png)
Please provide solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't have any limitations when it comes to national characters support, it might be the case you're running JMeter (and underlying Java) process using default [locale](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-internationalization/locale.html) which doesn't support Thai characters.

I cannot reproduce your issue using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

[image]

so you might want to try adding the following line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter instllation)

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)